# Doubts about the Buildroot configuration

Tags: linux, configuration, buildroot

How can I update my Buildroot without losing my configuration, packages, etc.?

And how can I update the Linux kernel that is configured? Is it just change the url from git repository in menuconfig? If someone helps me I will be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can update your Buildroot and keep your .config. Buildroot has a mechanism for handling legacy configurations, which will warn you if certain options have disappeared or been renamed.

You can also keep your packages, even though some changes might be needed as the package infrastructure evolves from time to time. However, we generally try to also have some logic to warn the user when the package uses some old/deprecated mechanisms.

Regarding your packages, I would however recommend to: 1/ submit to the official Buildroot all your packages for open-source components or generally publicly available software components, and 2/ use the BR2_EXTERNAL mechanism to separate your own private packages from the core of Buildroot.

Regarding the Linux kernel, it's entirely up to you in the Buildroot configuration to define which version you want to build. It can be a stable version downloaded as a tarball from kernel.org, a custom tarball location, or a custom Git tree.

Answer (score 0):

ty for the answers.

1. For update the buildroot do i have to type the command "git pull"?
2. For example, in .config the version of the Kernel is set like:

   > BR2_DEFAULT_KERNEL_VERSION="3.10.27" 
   >   BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CUSTOM_REPO_URL="git://github.com/raspberrypi/linux.git"
   >   BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CUSTOM_REPO_VERSION="943b563ec9961b53b77a0e7b6c07289826c082a5"
   >   BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_VERSION="943b563ec9961b53b77a0e7b6c07289826c082a5"

   What is the number referenced in "BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_VERSION"? If i want to change the version of Kernel to 3.12.X, do i have to change the number of the "BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CUSTOM_REPO_VERSION" and to type make? How can i find the reference of this number in repository?